# Meizu M3s не поддерживает XWALKVIEW

Tags: android

У меня обычное приложение, в котором я прогружаю свой сайт.

Почти везде всё работает и прогружается,но вот столкнулись с устройством Meizu m3s, на котором выбивает ошибку в XWalkView.

Помогите разобраться

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чём может быть проблема и как её решить,ибо на других устройствах всё работает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это [известный баг](https://bugs.launchpad.net/oxide/+bug/1590158). Семейство Meizu ограниченно поддерживает WebGL:

Comment: Эту проблему значит не решить,верно?